# How to improve a query with join to a table with a poor index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling with a query that I have inherited - the main problem is that there is join on what I would call a really poor index. Unfortunately there is no obvious way to improve the index, as far as I can see. Here's the select, explained:

```
mysql> explain
    -> SELECT
    ->     ug.stake,
    ->     COUNT(DISTINCT ug.game_instance_id) game_instance_count,
    ->     COUNT(DISTINCT ga.user_id) players,
    ->     SUM(total_stake_ga) total_stake_ga,
    ->     SUM(total_stake_ga) - SUM(total_win_ga) total_revenue_ga
    -> FROM game_tbl ug USE INDEX(SUG_IDX01)
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         ga2.game_instance_id,
    ->         ga2.user_id,
    ->         SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WAGER' THEN ga2.amount END) total_stake_ga,
    ->         SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WIN' THEN ga2.amount END) total_win_ga
    ->     FROM action ga2 USE INDEX(GA_IX03)
    ->     WHERE ga2.game_id IN (1104,1105)
    ->         AND ga2.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
    ->         AND ga2.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
    ->         AND ga2.currency = 'GBP'
    ->     GROUP BY
    ->         ga2.game_instance_id,
    ->         ga2.user_id
    ->     ) ga
    ->         ON ug.game_instance_id = ga.game_instance_id
    -> WHERE ug.game_id IN (1104,1105)
    ->     AND ug.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
    ->     AND ug.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
    -> GROUP BY
    ->     stake;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                 | rows     | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                |  7620079 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ug         | ref  | SUG_IDX01     | SUG_IDX01 | 8       | ga.game_instance_id |        1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ga2        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                | 66574831 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (4 min 31.40 sec)
```

And the indexes:

```
mysql> show indexes from game_tbl;
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name              | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| game_tbl         |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | game_tbl_id              | A         |    83522628 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| game_tbl         |          1 | SUG_IX01  |            1 | user_id                  | A         |     2784087 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| game_tbl         |          1 | SUG_IX01  |            2 | game_id                  | A         |     2197963 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| game_tbl         |          1 | SUG_FK02  |            1 | game_id                  | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| game_tbl         |          1 | SUG_FK03  |            1 | user_free_game_config_id | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| game_tbl         |          1 | SUG_IDX01 |            1 | game_instance_id         | A         |    83522628 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

and:

```
mysql> show indexes from action;
+-------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| action      |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | action_id         | A         |   435830016 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| action      |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            2 | created_timestamp | A         |   435830016 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| action      |          1 | GA_IX01                       |            1 | game_id           | A         |         174 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| action      |          1 | GA_IX02                       |            1 | user_id           | A         |     3301742 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| action      |          1 | GA_IX03                       |            1 | game_instance_id  | A         |   217915008 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| action      |          1 | action_created_timestamp      |            1 | created_timestamp | A         |    72638336 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (1.17 sec)
```

I can see how it is stupid to have a subquery, which I assume means creating a large, unindexed temporary table, which then causes one of the full table scans. However, the other full scan is harder - the `action` table contains >200 million rows, so each of the relatively few distinct values of the `game_id` key will cover a huge number of rows.

How can I improve the response time on this? I can't do anything about the nature of the data, and I can't change the design of the tables as such, but I am free to create new tables etc.

Comment: I don't think it's the join that causes the problem, but the group by and the where on the action table. What happens if you remove `USE INDEX(GA_IX03)` (I would focus on the timestamp and game id fields in the where clause)?

Comment: @Shadow removing the `use index` clauses made no difference

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - yes, I can try that. It will take a while, though. This is a production database (replicated from ..) so it is being used for heavy queries by other people.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Ah, but I realise that currency isn't from the same table as the other columns. I'll try to create one without currency

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `USE INDEX(..)` (index hints) in the outer SELECT query and inner Subquery. Most of the times Optimizer is good enough to figure out the best plan.
2. Define the following index on the `action` table, to avoid Full Table Scan in your Inner subquery:

```
ALTER TABLE action ADD INDEX(game_id, currency, created_timestamp);
```

General tip here is that add all the columns inside a `WHERE` clause to the index, if they are connected by `AND` and are compared to a constant value. In this case, `created_timestamp` is a Range condition, so we will add that column to the index at the end, because on encountering range condition, MySQL stops at the column, and does not access further columns in the index.

3. Define the following index on the `game_tbl` (to handle main SELECT query):

```
ALTER TABLE game_tbl ADD INDEX(game_id, created_timestamp);
```

4. You can also notice the `Using filesort` in the `Extra` column of your `EXPLAIN` result. This is happening because MySQL's default behavior is to sort the "grouped" results by the "grouped columns" order. This is really unnecessary in your case and is definitely a part of the performance issues here. Fortunately, [MySQL 8.0 has removed this default behaviour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> Previously (MySQL 5.7 and lower), GROUP BY sorted implicitly under
>   certain conditions. In MySQL 8.0, that no longer occurs, so specifying
>   ORDER BY NULL at the end to suppress implicit sorting (as was done
>   previously) is no longer necessary. However, query results may differ
>   from previous MySQL versions. To produce a given sort order, provide
>   an ORDER BY clause.

To fix this, we can add `ORDER BY NULL` inside the query.

Try the following query (after adding the indexes as explained above):

```
 SELECT
     ug.stake,
     COUNT(DISTINCT ug.game_instance_id) game_instance_count,
     COUNT(DISTINCT ga.user_id) players,
     SUM(total_stake_ga) total_stake_ga,
     SUM(total_stake_ga) - SUM(total_win_ga) total_revenue_ga
 FROM game_tbl ug /* removed USE INDEX */
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT
         ga2.game_instance_id,
         ga2.user_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WAGER' THEN ga2.amount END) total_stake_ga,
         SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WIN' THEN ga2.amount END) total_win_ga
     FROM action ga2 /* removed USE INDEX */
     WHERE ga2.game_id IN (1104,1105)
         AND ga2.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
         AND ga2.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
         AND ga2.currency = 'GBP'
     GROUP BY
         ga2.game_instance_id,
         ga2.user_id
     ORDER BY NULL  /* <-- order by null added here */
     ) ga
         ON ug.game_instance_id = ga.game_instance_id
 WHERE ug.game_id IN (1104,1105)
     AND ug.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
     AND ug.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY
     stake
 ORDER BY NULL   /* <-- order by null added here */
```

Please post the results of the steps explained here; we may need to use further hints like `STRAIGHT_JOIN` etc; but it all depends on how this new query and indexes perform.

===EDIT===
The outcome after the suggested changes (add indexes and change `SELECT`):

```
mysql> explain
    -> SELECT
    ->     ug.stake,
    ->     COUNT(DISTINCT ug.game_instance_id) game_instance_count,
    ->     COUNT(DISTINCT ga.user_id) players,
    ->     SUM(total_stake_ga) total_stake_ga,
    ->     SUM(total_stake_ga) - SUM(total_win_ga) total_revenue_ga
    -> FROM game_tbl ug
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         ga2.game_instance_id,
    ->         ga2.user_id,
    ->         SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WAGER' THEN ga2.amount END) total_stake_ga,
    ->         SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WIN' THEN ga2.amount END) total_win_ga
    ->     FROM action ga2 /* removed USE INDEX */
    ->     WHERE ga2.game_id IN (1104,1105)
    ->         AND ga2.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
    ->         AND ga2.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
    ->         AND ga2.currency = 'GBP'
    ->     GROUP BY
    ->         ga2.game_instance_id,
    ->         ga2.user_id
    ->     ORDER BY NULL  /* <-- order by null added here */
    ->     ) ga
    ->         ON ug.game_instance_id = ga.game_instance_id
    -> WHERE ug.game_id IN (1104,1105)
    ->     AND ug.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
    ->     AND ug.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
    -> GROUP BY
    ->     stake
    -> ORDER BY NULL;
+----+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                                         | key       | key_len | ref                 | rows     | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL                                                  | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                |  7620079 | Using temporary              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ug         | ref  | SUG_FK02,SUG_IDX01,sug_id_cur_tstmp                   | SUG_IDX01 | 8       | ga.game_instance_id |        1 | Using where                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ga2        | ALL  | GA_IX01,action_created_timestamp,ga_id_cur_tstmp | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                | 64601255 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (4 min 18.68 sec)
```

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` only works great when values are existing in the table.. For missing values you will mis a possible optimisation -> *"Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"* so the query still need to fully table/index scan..

Comment: @RaymondNijland hmm.. good to know. Although I generally dont use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` .. that is why I am waiting for OP to first post the results of the other activities like indexing, and using `order by null`.

Comment: in cases like these i wished MySQL optimizer would support JOIN precedence with parenthesis.. As it can be very tricky to optimize JOIN with ORDER BY in MySQL because MySQL might access the "wrong" table first and needs to use a temporary table instead of pipelined execution..

Comment: @RaymondNijland well we all have a bucket-list of things that we would want optimizer to handle *automatically* and *rewrite queries* for us :-) ; but it eventually makes the algorithm way too complex and error prone in edge cases. I like an algorithm which is simple and works in most of the **practical** use cases, and a person like me (non-MySQL source coder) can also understand :-) Having learnt the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) hard way; I now continuously argue with my business/operations team on keeping the features simple yet effective.

Comment: indeed you also want to avoid that optimization step takes more time then selecting it ..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - thank you for your comments. I didn't have time yesterday, but I'll try your suggestions now.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n yeah please do. I will be interested in outcome of this; solving real-life problems gives much more practical insight..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It took quite a while to create the index; unfortunately it didn't really change anything (I would post the output of the explain of your select, but I don't think it will fit here - should I put it in an edit of your reply?)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n how many rows are there in both the tables, if you do a plain select on each one of them using the specified conditions ?

Comment: @j4nd3r53n let's chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199611/for-question-https-stackoverflow-com-q-57972267-2469308 

I will need you to run a few queries to try other things, but for that we need to discuss, and cant be done here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the research purpose, Can you please try running your inner-sub query and below query separately -

```
SELECT ga2.game_instance_id
      ,ga2.user_id
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WAGER' THEN ga2.amount END) total_stake_ga
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WIN' THEN ga2.amount END) total_win_ga  FROM action ga2 USE INDEX(GA_IX03)
WHERE ga2.game_id = 1104
AND ga2.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
AND ga2.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
AND ga2.currency = 'GBP'
GROUP BY ga2.game_instance_id
        ,ga2.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT ga2.game_instance_id
      ,ga2.user_id
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WAGER' THEN ga2.amount END) total_stake_ga
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN ga2.`type` = 'WIN' THEN ga2.amount END) total_win_ga  FROM action ga2 USE INDEX(GA_IX03)
WHERE ga2.game_id = 1105
AND ga2.created_timestamp >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00'
AND ga2.created_timestamp <= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'
AND ga2.currency = 'GBP'
GROUP BY ga2.game_instance_id
        ,ga2.user_id
```

I guess having `IN` condition in where clause not letting you use Indexes. If it improves performance for you inner query only, You can then tune your whole query.